# Android LocationListener crash

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I'm trying to enable/disable GPS services by a ToggleButton. The app starts with the button unchecked, and GPS services are disabled (as they should be). They turn on successfully and works great **BUT** when I turn it off again, it crashes. Here's the code:

```
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener locationListener = null;
    final ToggleButton gpsButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.gpsButton);


    gpsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (gpsButton.isChecked()) {
                 LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.

                        //doing some stuff with locations


                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                  };
                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, seconds, 0, locationListener);
            }
            else {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat stack trace as it describes the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `locationListener` outside of the `onClickListener`, but then creating a new local `locationListener` variable when the user clicks the button.

It is still `null` when you try to remove updates from it because you have created a different variable. Remove the type declaration from `locationListener` in the `onClick` method, so it becomes

```
...
if (gpsButton.isChecked()) {
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! But there's this little problem, if I don't declare it in the onClick it gives me an error that it's final and I can't change it. When I remove the "final" from the initial declaration on the top, it gives me an error that I need to make it final.

Comment: True... then you should initialize it when you declare it, instead of setting it to `null`, use the constructor `new LocationListener() { ...`

Comment: Yeah that way works, but I want to enable it only when the togglebutton is pressed. That way it will be enabled by default, right?

Comment: No, the listener will be created but it will not be 'enabled' until you call `requestLocationUpdates`.

Comment: Thanks, So I'll just put the requestLocationUpdates into the if (gpsButton.isChecked()).